# Ajaxify (callback method)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

Currently using [Ajaxify](https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify) which is working out great, but perhaps someone may know the answer to this.

Is there a callback we can use without having to input specific needs into the script?

I've tried hunting around, but I'm keen to add a few callbacks once the ajax method has completed; or better yet, an option beforeAjax and afterAjax.

Thanks,
R

Answer (score 0):

you can use the statechangecomplete event included. [bottom of page](https://github.com/prod4ever/ajaxify)